# Talend > NullPointerException on tFileUnarchive

Tags: java, talend

I am attempting to build an import tool using Talend Open Studio 6.1.1, which will import various tab-delimited .txt files that have been compressed into a ZIP file.

To accomplish this, I'm using the **tFileUnarchive** component.  The **Archive File** for this component is set to "context.RECORD1", where RECORD1 is the file path to the ZIP.

As such, the **Extraction Directory** is set to "context.RECORD1.substring(0,context.RECORD1.lastIndexOf("/"))".

This component then is connected to various **tFileInputDelimited** components using Trigger > Run If.  The condition in the **Run If**, for example, will be:

```
globalMap.get("tFileExist_1_FILENAME").toString().contains("VAM")
```

to extract one of the tab-delimited files (within the ZIP) that has "VAM" in its name.  However, the job fails with the following error output:

```
Exception in component tFileUnarchive_2
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at map_2016.map2016_0_1.map2016.tFileUnarchive_2Process(map2016.java:2027)
    at map_2016.map2016_0_1.map2016.tPostgresqlConnection_1Process(map2016.java:1764)
    at map_2016.map2016_0_1.map2016.runJobInTOS(map2016.java:48371)
    at map_2016.map2016_0_1.map2016.main(map2016.java:48186)
```

One thing to note: I'm not using *all* of the tab-delimited .txt files that are contained in the original ZIP, as some of them are not relevant to my purposes.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

`globalMap.get("tFileExist_1_FILENAME").toString().contains("VAM")`

globalMap **or** the result of `globalMap.get(...)` **or** return of `.toString()` is null.

see also: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks, that answered the question!